# Rails 6 Issue with Bootstrap 5 Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following dropdown menu on my app:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-sand-light py-4">

  <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand ps-4" do %>
    LOGO GOES HERE
    <%#= image_tag "Logo.png", style: "width: 100px" %>
  <% end %>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse me-4" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Who We Are</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Partners
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Become a Partner</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Meet Our Partners</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ms-2">
        <a class="btn mt-1 btn-bold" href="#">Donate</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In theory, I'm using Bootstrap 5.0.1 with the following gems:

```
# RAILS GENERATED STUFF
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# OTHER NECESSARY STUFF
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'gon'

# ESSENTIALS
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.0.1'
```

Here is my `application.js`:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
ActiveStorage.start()


//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap

//= require popper
//= require activestorage
//= require font_awesome5
//= require tinymce

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

The dropdown does not work.

If I add this script tag in my header, manually loading Bootstrap 5 Alpha, the dropdown works:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-popRpmFF9JQgExhfw5tZT4I9/CI5e2QcuUZPOVXb1m7qUmeR2b50u+YFEYe1wgzy" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However, if I manually load Bootstrap 5.0.2 in the exact same location using the cdn link in the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), it doesn't work.  This is very mysterious.

I have it taped together for now, but I'd really love to get Bootstrap working using the actual asset pipeline.

Can any Rails 6 wizards see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to use the asset pipeline or webpacker? First impression is that most of your code suggestions webpack is being used by your mentioning asset pipeline.

Comment: @JayKilleen I'm new to Rails 6 and honestly didn't know the difference.  I'll go with whatever the best practice is for Rails 6?

Comment: Rails 6 has more recently switched from the asset pipeline to using webpack (via the webpacker gem) to server javascript/css assets etc. More recently (6.1.x) and onwards they've (through hotwire) dipped back into the utility of asset pipeline.

If all you are doing is integrating a css framework, then I would go with asset pipeline. If you want 'more' JS functionality (ie tailwindcss, a js frontend framework like vue/react or want to use stimulusJS) then I would recommend the webpack route.

Comment: My experience is pretty limited so this is just a 'what I would do'.  Going from your Gemfile and also Bootstrap coming with JS functionality (ie jquery-ui etc) then I would go with webpacker.

Comment: @excid3 (Chris) from Gorails has a video on this you might want to check out https://gorails.com/episodes/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-webpack-and-rails but seems you might just need to check if you have webpacker installed/configured correctly (ie did you `rails new app_name --webpack` (back of my mind I think rails new in 6.1.x does this as a default but I could be wrong).

Comment: So just confiming "Webpacker is installed by default in Rails 6.0 and up. You can install it with a new project in some older versions by adding --webpack to the rails new command. Webpacker can be added in an existing project by running bin/rails webpacker:install" which can all be read at the edge guides at https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html